# How to reset session cookies using Gdata APIs

Tags: google-provisioning-api

using the  Provisioning API, does setting changePasswordAtNextLogin to true also reset the current sign-in cookies?

If not, is there a way to reset these cookies via API (close all active sessions)?

Or is this a functionality only available in the control panel?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting changePasswordAtNextLogin does not reset the users session cookies.

There is no API equivalent to the CPanel reset cookies setting.

Comment: well, thats a bummer. I did find this in the issue tracker as a requested functionality:
http://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2849

Answer (score 0):

Updating this since things have changed in 11 years.

You can not logout users using the ADMIN SDK API

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/signOut